# How to make a dynamic LINQ query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

There are two tables User and Role. I have to fetch the data with respect to the request in Entity frame work. This is my request class

```
public class UserRequestDTO
{
    public Int64? RoleId {get;set;}
    public Int64? DepartmentId {get;set;}
}
```

This is my Data Access Layer

```
public IList<User> GetUser(UserRequestDTO _oUserRequestDTO)
{
    ///This Implements the DbContext
    DataContext _odb=new DataContext();

    IQueryable<User> query=_odb.user.where(a=>a.IsDisable.equals(false));

    if(_oUserRequestDTO.RoleId.HasValue)
    {
        query=  from qu in query
                from role in _odb.Role.where(a=>a.Id.equals(qu.RoleId))
                Where role.Id.equals(RoleId)&& role.IsDisable.equals(false))
                Select qu;
    }

    if(_oUserRequestDTO.DepartmentId.HasValue)
    {
        query=  from qu in query
                from role in _odb.Role.where(a=>a.Id.equals(qu.RoleId))
                Where role.Department.Id.equals(DepartmentId)&& role.IsDisable.equals(false))
                Select qu;
    }
    IList<User> UserLst=query.ToList();
    return UserLst;
}
```

I check what query is firing in the SQL Server 2014 Profiler. If I am filtering with RoleId or DepartmentId in the request no problem in the query. But if I filter with both RoleId and DepartmentId. In the Profiler I saw two inner join where coming.

How can I make it into a single inner join?

Is there any way to learn about how query will be generated through Linq?

Comment: why you get two inner join? Entity Framework queries are "deferred" queries. They don't actually run until you start asking for results. Based on your code, the query will triggered at `IList<User> UserLst=query.ToList();`

Comment: What exactly result do you want to achieve? And show us what sql did you see in profiler. Show us your entity class (Role and User) and its EF mapping also.

Comment: Hi Krill, 
I am sorry for this question, Do u want me to edit my question?

Comment: Hi vantian,
I got that problem is there any way to fix it. Please let me know.

Comment: Isn't there a `User.Roles` navigation property? If not, you should create it.

Comment: Hi Gert Arnold,
In my User Role object is not there, we are having only the role id in the User.

Answer (score 0):

Select common part of query in one variable:

```
public IList<User> GetUser(UserRequestDTO _oUserRequestDTO)
{
    DataContext _odb = new DataContext();

    var users =_odb.user.where(a=>a.IsDisable.equals(false));

    var query = from qu in users
                from role in _odb.Role.where(a=>a.Id.equals(qu.RoleId))
                select new { User = qu, Role = role };


    if(_oUserRequestDTO.RoleId.HasValue)
    {
        query = from o in query
                where o.Role.Id.equals(RoleId) && o.Role.IsDisable.equals(false))
                select o;
    }

    if(_oUserRequestDTO.DepartmentId.HasValue)
    {
        query = from o in query
                where o.Role.Department.Id.equals(DepartmentId) && o.Role.IsDisable.equals(false))
                select o;
    }
    return query.Select(o => o.User).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi Backs,
I can't write this query because in my user class i am not having object  of role and i am just having the RoleId column

Comment: @GopinathNavannethan I don't get `Role` from `User` class. Look at my query, I created new class `new { User = qu, Role = role }`

Comment: Hi Backs, 
Thanks Let me try this :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use to Expression --> [LINQ to Entities: Combining Predicates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx)

```
 public IList<User> GetUser(UserRequestDTO _oUserRequestDTO)
    {
        ///This Implements the DbContext
        DataContext _odb=new DataContext();
    Expression<Func<User, bool>> expresionWhere =a=>a.IsDisable.equals(false);



        if(_oUserRequestDTO.RoleId.HasValue)
        {

Expression<Func<User, bool>> expresionRoleId = UserRequestDTO.RoleId =RoleId  && !Role.IsDisable);
                expresionWhere= PredicateBuilder.And(expresionWhere, expresionRoleId );
        }

        if(_oUserRequestDTO.DepartmentId.HasValue)
        {

Expression<Func<User, bool>> expresionDepartmentId = UserRequestDTO.DepartmentId=DepartmentId && !Role.IsDisable);
                expresionWhere= PredicateBuilder.And(expresionWhere, expresionDepartmentId );
        }


        IList<User> UserLst=odb.user.Include("UserRequestDTO").Where(expresionWhere).toList();
        return UserLst;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Let me try this :-)